# Google Places API doesn't show all locations in custom app

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

From research I've learnt that Google Maps and Google Places are not the same thing, but can someone confirm this deduction: does that cause the app to not show all the locations that are shown in Google Maps (let's assume because the business owner didn't list it in Google Places)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect the Maps API Web Services and the Google Maps website to work in the exact same way at all times. The Google Maps website gathers data from many different sources. Also, the search stack is different. Due to this, you may find differences between the results of these two services, and you should not use Google Maps website results blind eyed as a control group for your Web Services requests. You can find confirmation that Web Services and maps.google.com can show different results in the Google Maps API FAQ at https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences.